# Process that sent SIGKILL

Tags: linux, kill, signals

I have a series of scripts that are being killed (`$?` says exit code is 137, which implies a `kill -9` scenario). I need to know what process killed them. Is there a way to find out this information?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there's any way to retrieve the pid of the process that sends the kill, at least from within another process.  The signal is sent via a kernel interrupt, and as far as I know, it's only the kernel that knows which process sent it.

That being said, if you're comfortable with patching the kernel to find this out, you might take a look at this:  [patching the kernel to log signals](http://www.superfrink.net/code/sig2/siglog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 137 references a time out signal.

Read [this page on exit codes and signals](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/BFROOT/www/Computing/Environment/Tools/Batch/exitcode.html)

I'd also suggest looking for the OOM issue in the /var/log/messages folder.

Comment: From your link: `... exit code 137 means that the job received a signal 9 ...`; this is not a time out signal.

Comment: forgive me that was under the hypernews section. Have you checked out the /var/log/messages ?

Comment: Yes, and regarding any kills, it is empty.